# ring network in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I want to build a ring topology using android emulators.
Currently my application has both client and server.
How can I run the same instance of my program on different emulators?
i.e. how to set the re directions on different emulators (redir add ?)?
Can anybody give me some pointers regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be built by making connection to all emulators provided we redirected all the emulator port to same port.
for example : 
if we want to connect 3 devices in ring passion 
we have to set up one redirection to server port for each emulators
2.i.e redir add tcp 4444:8000 redir add tcp 4445:8000 redir add tcp 4446:8000 in 3 diff emulators.
2.create server on each emulator at 8000 port.
3.connect to port 8000 from all the emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running your app from Eclipse you can go to the menu "Run" > "RunConfigurations..." This will show a window with all the available configurations. Select the one from android that you want to run on different emulators and select the tab "Target". 
Once in there select Manual instead of Automatic. This will prompt you where you want to deploy. You may have to create more than one AVD so you can launch more than one emulator.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. I know how to open more than one emulator my concern is how to setup redirection in different emulator i.e. how to run server on different ports and so clients using same instance of program